# Reshape time series data from wide to long for multiple variables

Tags: r, pivot-table, reshape

I'm working with time series data in wide(ish) format for many columns that all have the format "T1_v1_slow"..."T4_v1_slow" and "T1_v1_fast"..."T4_v1_fast". There are 42 variables with this format in total. I'm trying to use `pivot_longer` to return each variable as a column (e.g., "v1_total", "v1_Vig), with a single column for time. Example data below:

| ParticipantNumber | T1_v1_total | T2_v1_total | T3_v1_total | T4_v1_total | T1_v1_Vig | T2_v1_Vig | T3_v1_Vig | T4_v1_Vig |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41 | 47 | 45 | 28 | 8 | 5 | 8 | 11 |
| 2 | 16 | 25 | -4 | -4 | 11 | 10 | 18 | 17 |

I can get the data in truly long format using

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ParticipantNumber) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("time", "name"), sep = 3)
```

Output

| ParticipantNumber | time | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1_ | v1_total | 41 |
| 1 | T2_ | v1_total | 47 |
| 1 | T3_ | v1_total | 45 |
| 1 | T4_ | v1_total | 28 |
| 1 | T1_ | v1_Vig | 8 |
| 1 | T2_ | v1_Vig | 5 |
| 1 | T3_ | v1_Vig | 8 |
| 1 | T4_ | v1_Vig | 11 |
| 2 | T1_ | v1_total | 16 |
| 2 | T2_ | v1_total | 25 |
| 2 | T3_ | v1_total | -4 |
| 2 | T4_ | v1_total | -4 |
| 2 | T1_ | v1_Vig | 11 |
| 2 | T2_ | v1_Vig | 10 |
| 2 | T3_ | v1_Vig | 18 |
| 2 | T4_ | v1_Vig | 17 |

I can't use `sep = "_"` because I don't want to grab the second `_`. My desired output is:

| ParticipantNumber | time | v1_Vig | v1_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1_ | 8 | 41 |
| 1 | T2_ | 5 | 47 |
| 1 | T3_ | 8 | 45 |
| 1 | T4_ | 5 | 28 |
| 2 | T1_ | 11 | 16 |
| 2 | T2_ | 10 | 25 |
| 2 | T3_ | 18 | -4 |
| 2 | T4_ | 17 | -4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use pivot_wider

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ParticipantNumber) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("time", "name"), sep = 3) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn=sum)
```

Comment: Thank you. Never occurred to me to combine pivot_wider with pivot_longer.

Comment: You're welcome. I think pivot_wider works with no further arguments because default "names_from" is "name" and "values_from" is "value", and those are the names already in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(
  ParticipantNumber = c(1L, 2L),
        T1_v1_total = c(41L, 16L),
        T2_v1_total = c(47L, 25L),
        T3_v1_total = c(45L, -4L),
        T4_v1_total = c(28L, -4L),
          T1_v1_Vig = c(8L, 11L),
          T2_v1_Vig = c(5L, 10L),
          T3_v1_Vig = c(8L, 18L),
          T4_v1_Vig = c(11L, 17L)
) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ParticipantNumber, names_to = c("time", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.)_(.*)")

## A tibble: 8 × 4
#  ParticipantNumber time  v1_total v1_Vig
#              <int> <chr>    <int>  <int>
#1                 1 1           41      8
#2                 1 2           47      5
#3                 1 3           45      8
#4                 1 4           28     11
#5                 2 1           16     11
#6                 2 2           25     10
#7                 2 3           -4     18
#8                 2 4           -4     17
```